# How to create a folder under /Android/obb?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to use expansion files and I found an issue that I'm not able to resolve.

It seems that you can access the `/Android/obb` folder and eventually delete the `/Android/obb/my.package.name` directory (tried with some file manager), but I cannot handle this situation whithin the app.

If I just let the Google Downloader library try to download the expansion file it will hang and error (for the missing folder), but it will start if I recreate the folder.

The strange thing is that I'm able to create the folder from other apps (the same file manager that I've used to see the directory) **but not from mine**!

I tried with

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/obb/my.package.name");
f.mkdirs();
```

but it doesn't work.

I've the permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I'm targeting api 23 and compiling with the 25.

Comment: Do you get the pop up to accept the permission on runtime ? Have you implemented the dangerous permission flow?

Comment: Nope, that's why I'm targeting the api 23. I just don't want to mess with all the hassles of the permissions. Do I have to?

Comment: @android_Muncher f**, I was thinking that I needed to target 23, but actually they INTRODUCED the runtime permissions with 23. :/
Now targeting the 22 it works. Do you want to answer the question and get the points? You actually helped me on spotting the issue. :)

Comment: give me some credit :)

Comment: Thanks, I've had to wait few minutes in order to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP dropped the Target SDK to 22 and was able to avoid Dangerous permission work flow which was causing the issue.

Comment: At this time, Google is making it impossible to use Target SDK to 22 to avoid Dangerous Permissions workflow.

Answer (score 1):

### [I had this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54093011/4571656), but lowering the Target SDK was not an option.

The [`Context::getObbDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getObbDir()) method allows access to the expansion folder without the usual security rules. I found that, if the folder doesn't exist, `getObbDir()` creates it too (You can also double check and create it manually with `mkdir()`).

Excerpt from the documentation linked above:

> Return the primary shared/external storage directory where this application's OBB files (if there are any) can be found. Note if the application does not have any OBB files, this directory may not exist.
>
> This is like `getFilesDir()` in that these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled, however there are some important differences:
>
> ... Starting in `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT`, no permissions are required to read or write to the path that this method returns. ...
>
> Starting from `Build.VERSION_CODES.N`, `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is not required, so don’t ask for this permission at runtime. ...

So you can do something like:

```
File obbDir = getObbDir();

if (null == obbDir) {
    // Storage is not available
} else  if (!obbDir.exists() && !obbDir.mkdir()) {
    // Failed to create directory. Shouldn't happen but you never know.
}
```

**NOTE:** You may need the read/write permissions to access the expansion *files* within the folder.