# Is there a way to manually create the package folder for an APK's .obb file?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm having an issue with an app: (rarely) a user will download the app from the play store but the obb/expansion file will fail to download. If the folder for the obb file is created (`Android/obb/my.package.name`), that's fine, I can manually download the obb file without a problem.

However, if the folder for the obb file was not created, attempting to create it with `File::mkdir()` or `File::mkdirs()` fails (returns false). Attempting to create and write to the obb file without a directory throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
File obbFile = new File("path/to/obb/file.obb");

File parent = obbFile.getParentFile();

if (!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdir()) {
    // Failed to create directory
}
```

External read/write permissions are set up and working correctly as we can read/write/create other files/directories with no issue.

I've read [How to create a folder under /Android/obb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45337142/4571656) but the only solution given to that is to drop the target sdk to 22.

Has anyone else come across this and found a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Context::getObbDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getObbDir()) method allows access to the expansion folder without the usual security rules. I found that, if the folder doesn't exist, `getObbDir()` creates it too (You can also double check create it manually with `mkdir()`).

Excerpt from the documentation linked above:

> Return the primary shared/external storage directory where this application's OBB files (if there are any) can be found. Note if the application does not have any OBB files, this directory may not exist.
>
> This is like `getFilesDir()` in that these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled, however there are some important differences:
>
> ... Starting in `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT`, no permissions are required to read or write to the path that this method returns. ...
>
> Starting from `Build.VERSION_CODES.N`, `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is not required, so don’t ask for this permission at runtime. ...

So the code in the question can become:

```
File obbDir = getObbDir();

if (null == obbDir) {
    // Storage is not available
} else  if (!obbDir.exists() && !obbDir.mkdir()) {
    // Failed to create directory. Shouldn't happen but you never know.
}
```

**NOTE:** You may need the read/write permissions to access the expansion *files* within the folder. See the documentation for more info.